# Using Keras ImageDataGenerator predictions for indexing raises unhashable type error

Tags: python, indexing, keras

I have created a classifier for [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), created using `flow_from_directory` such as:

```
training_imGenProp = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    width_shift_range=0.02,
    height_shift_range=0.02,
)

training_imGen = training_imGenProp.flow_from_directory(
    'Location/to/train/images',
    target_size=(74, 448),
    batch_size=batchSize,
    class_mode='binary',
)
```

When running it, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` in the last row of the following code snippet:

```
predictions = classifier.predict_generator(testing_imGen)
predictions = (predictions >= 0.5).astype(int)
label_map = (training_imGen.class_indices)
inverted_label_map = dict((v, k) for k, v in label_map.items())  #flip k,v
predictions = [label_map[k] for k in predictions]
```

What might be causing it?

Additionally, how should I proceed to generate a confusion matrix from this classifier results?

This:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(label_map, predictions).ravel()
```

raises an error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2,(663, 1)]`.

Comment: The issue is surely here `label_map = dict((v,k) for k,v in label_map.items()) #flip k,v`, the type of `k` is a `numpy.ndarray`? If so, it is just saying that you cannot use that as a key for a dictionary because it is not an hashable type (there is no hash function for that type).

Comment: Also, please include some dummy generators for the dataset and classifier for reproducing the error as, as of now, I cannot run the code.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I did add the code. I don't know whether `k` is a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: From where is `ImageDataGenerator ` imported? Also, just run `type(k)` to discover the type.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti `from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`. It takes several hours to re-train the model and check the type actually. Wouldn't there be any convenient method?

Comment: I'm quite convinced that this error would present itself even with a single neuron and no training, if it is just a typing one. Since I have no access to the images, could you create a dummy matrix to test the code? Otherwise could you just run the code commenting the training bit?

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I've the saved model. But since this method require `train_generator` for class_indices, I had to re-train the model. I don't know any other way of getting training class indices from saved model. This is just a binary classification (Cats vs Dogs)

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute still be there, of course untrained, but still be there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177403/discussion-between-sam94-and-luca-cappelletti).

Comment: You're not making our jobs easier, buddy. Please provide a minimal, working code that reproduces your error. We need this if you want us to effectively help you.

Comment: @Fred I know it's better to supply the dataset to reproduce the error. But my dataset is huge to upload here. I've added a link to download it.

Comment: Ok but we don't need the dataset to reproduce your error, we just need a dummy numpy generator, such as a `my_dataset = np.random.uniform(size=(size of my dataset))`. There is no requirement that it actually does something or holds any information, only that it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after long lucubrations the issue was within the last list comprehension, as `predictions` was a column numpy array, such as `[[1],[1],[0], ..., [0]]`.

So it was just necessary to access the integer values within:

```
textual_predictions = [s_label_map[k] for k in predictions.T[0]]
```

Additionally there was another error creating the **confusion matrix**, that had the wrong variables as input:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(testing_imGen.classes, predictions.T[0]).ravel()
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you very much